# Android studio help how to detect when a song is finish

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to automatically play a song once the first song finish, the issue is that I don't know how to tell when the first song is finish. Code is below, I'm trying to play mediaPlayer2 after mediaPlayer is done playing.
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, mediaPlayer2;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // global variable
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, mediaPlayer2;

    public void play(View view)
    {
        // play music if you want this to start from the beginning put this in oncreate method
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // set loop
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }



    public void pause(View view)
    {
        // pause music
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create media player variable and link it to the music you want
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);

        mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);

    }
}
```

Comment: probably you need to use `setOnCompletionListener`

Comment: In this case, why **mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);** ?

Comment: ops that was by accident I meant to remove that, and where would I set the setOnCompletionListener which method

Comment: Why did you remove all of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListner(New OnCompletionListener {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        //add your code here

    } 
)};
```

Comment: does this on in the onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, after the media player is initilized.

Comment: question, I added in a third song and i put it all into an array so like mediaPlayer[i].setOnCompletionListner, but it won't go call this method again once the second songs ends. This method is only call once the first method ends

Answer (score 1):

set OnCompletionListener helps you
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

```
 mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   // Do Whatever You want
                }
            });
```